# Variable not defined - iterating through AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have an array that consists of 4 numbers. My script should iterate through AD, only for enabled accounts where extensionAttribute7 is equal to 1, 2, 5 or 6. When I run it, I get a message

Get-ADUser: Variable: 'printExtensionAttribute7' found in expression: $printExtensionAttribute7 is not defined.

If I output the variable, it does contain the 4 numbers - any ideas?

```
$printExtensionAttribute7 = @('1','2','5','6')
$ADUsers = Get-ADUser -server xxx.yyy.net -Filter { enabled -eq $true -and ($printExtensionAttribute7 -contains $_.extensionAttribute7)} -Properties Description, POBox , Office, Department, extensionAttribute7
```

Answer (score 1):

Operators like `-contains` and `-match` are not supported by the [Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)), what you can do is construct a filter clause for each `extensionAttribute7`.

```
$filter = -join @(
    '(&'                                                  # AND, all conditions must be met
        '(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)' # Enabled object
        '(|'                                              # OR, any of the conditions must be met
            1, 2, 5, 6 | ForEach-Object {                 # loop over each value for "extensionAttribute7"
                '(extensionAttribute7={0})' -f $_         # and construct a filter clause for each one
            }
        ')'                                               # close OR
    ')'                                                   # close AND
)

$getADUserSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = $filter
    Server     = 'xxx.yyy.net'
    Properties = 'Description', 'POBox', 'Office', 'Department', 'extensionAttribute7'
}

Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat
```